# R xts calculating percentage index on multiple series

Tags: r, xts

I have an `xts` object with changing numbers of columns but always the same index. I want to get a percentage index based on the the first element of each series.

For example with **one** column:

```
library(xts)

x <- xts(1:10,as.Date("2012-12-21")+1:10)
x

z<-(x / drop(coredata(first(x, 1))))*100
z
```

Is there a way to run this calculation on each column if the numbers of columns can be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `apply`, and I would prefer `apply` over `sapply` because `apply` coerces its first argument to a matrix. And that simplifies the function needed to operate on each column.

I'll use the same `x` from [tonytonov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645211/271616).

```
R> x <- xts(matrix(1:20, ncol = 2),as.Date("2012-12-21") + 1:10)
R> as.xts(apply(x, 2, function(v) 100*v/v[1]))
           [,1]     [,2]
2012-12-22  100 100.0000
2012-12-23  200 109.0909
2012-12-24  300 118.1818
2012-12-25  400 127.2727
2012-12-26  500 136.3636
2012-12-27  600 145.4545
2012-12-28  700 154.5455
2012-12-29  800 163.6364
2012-12-30  900 172.7273
2012-12-31 1000 181.8182
```

Notice that you don't need the calls to `coredata` or `drop` because `apply` coerces `x` to a matrix first (by calling `as.matrix.xts`). That means `v` is a simple numeric vector. This also makes it easier to coerce the output of `apply` back to an xts object by using `as.xts`.

Answer (score 1):

Given a series like

```
x <- xts(matrix(1:20, ncol = 2),as.Date("2012-12-21") + 1:10)
```

one can use e.g. `sapply` like so:

```
xts(sapply(x, function(y) 100 * y / as.numeric(y[1, ])), index(x))
            x.1   x.2
2012-12-22  100 100.0
2012-12-23  200 109.1
2012-12-24  300 118.2
2012-12-25  400 127.3
2012-12-26  500 136.4
2012-12-27  600 145.5
2012-12-28  700 154.5
2012-12-29  800 163.6
2012-12-30  900 172.7
2012-12-31 1000 181.8
```